# PHP utf8 with idiorm and mysql

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, localhost, idiorm

I use WAMP to run PHP code on localhost. The problem is that on my localhost I get utf8 errors like "lÃ¥n". On the live server I get "lån" like suspected.

**What I've tried so far**

- Set database table on server and localhost to `utf8_general_ci`
- Set database table structure rows on server and localhost to `utf8_general_ci`
- Checked file encoding with [utf cast](http://www.rotatingscrew.com/utfcast-professional.aspx), they are set `ASCII/UTF-8, NO BOM` on both server and localhost
- Forced PHP header with `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- Forced UTF8 to database with `ORM::configure('mysql:host=SECRET;dbname=SECRET;charset=utf8');`
- Added `ORM::configure('driver_options', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));` with no luck

**More info**

- The data are identical in the database when I use phpmyadmin. I even used a diff tool.
- The data are not identical on output. **Why not? What to do?**
- I use [idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm) for nice SQL.
- The databases settings are the same.
- The files are the same. I upload them to the server.
- I have filezilla to send them as binary.

I just want the localhost and the server to show the same, without if statement workaround. I don't want utf8_decode on one place and not on the other.

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: What about ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but I had to put `$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");` before `@$dom->loadHTML($html);` that I have in my code.

I still don't know why it doesn't work without it when localhost and server settings are equal in every way.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the [documentation](http://idiorm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#pdo-driver-options) you have to do this configuration:

```
<?php
ORM::configure('driver_options', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```